# Reflexive form of "arrêter" for habits

Tags: verbes, pronoms-réfléchis

> Après plusieurs tentatives, elle a finalement arrêté de fumer.
>
> Après plusieurs tentatives, elle s'est finalement arrêtée de fumer.

Which one is correct, or both? If both are correct, is there a difference in meaning? This [dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/s-arr%C3%AAter) has the example *s'arrêter de fumer*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are very common, and sound correct. However, it looks like the correctness of the second one could be in question.

[CNRTL](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/arr%C3%AAter) gives only this (non reflexive) example for *arrêter de*, and I did not see the reflexive *s'arrêter **de*** anywhere on that page:

> 25. L'idée de revoir les lieux où s'était passée sa jeunesse l'exaltait sans doute, car tout le long du chemin il **n'arrêta pas de discourir**; ... Flaubert, Madame Bovary,t. 2, 1857, p. 130.

LBU, 14ème édition, 2008, accepts *s'arrêter **de*** with multiple examples from various authors, without commenting further than to say: "*On dit aussi*". For example:

> Elle me reprenait sans **s'arrêter de travailler** (Péguy, Souvenir, p. 17).
>
> Même les marins italiens **s'étaient arrêtés de bouger** (Le Clézio, Etoile errante, p. 202).

So, I would say that both forms are correct, even in writing, by now. I can see how the second one is "questionable": Péguy could have written *elle me reprenait sans arrêter de travailler* and it would have been the same, because, in the end, **who** is stopping? There is only one subject here, only one possibility for the subject who carries out the action of stopping. So, you could make a case that there is really *no need* for that ***s'*** in terms of clarity. Removing it is more concise, without any loss. On the other hand, the author might want to add that ***s'***, either to underscore who is doing the action, or to soften the expression.

I am adding some preliminary data from ngrams, that needs to be reviewed and criticized (I am very aware that I queried only for the infinitive forms)(the trend is the same for *s'arrêter de fumer* et *arrêter de fumer*):

[image]

Comment: That's interesting. This [dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/s-arr%C3%AAter) has the example *s'arrêter de fumer*.

Comment: Interesting. Yes, the expression is very common. I'll go back to CNRTL, I must have missed it.

Comment: It's not in CNRTL, but LBU has an interesting paragraph about it. BLU gives the reflexive form as familiar and spoken only, apparently. You have hit upon a really interesting question! :-)

Answer (score 1):

> Après plusieurs tentatives, elle a finalement arrêté de fumer.

This one is always correct: She quit smoking.

> Après plusieurs tentatives, elle s'est finalement arrêtée de fumer.

That one is also commonly used but is ambiguous: She stopped smoking. It might be understood to mean she smoked **continuously** until she stopped.

[Google NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/interactive_chart?content=(il+a+arr%C3%AAt%C3%A9+de+%2B+elle+a+arr%C3%AAt%C3%A9)%2C(il+s'est+arr%C3%AAt%C3%A9+de%2Belle+s'est+arr%C3%AAt%C3%A9e+de)&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C(il%20a%20arr%C3%AAt%C3%A9%20de%20%2B%20elle%20a%20arr%C3%AAt%C3%A9)%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C(il%20s'est%20arr%C3%AAt%C3%A9%20de%20%2B%20elle%20s'est%20arr%C3%AAt%C3%A9e%20de)%3B%2Cc0)
[image: Google NGram]

Comment: On dirait que nos recherches dans ngrams coïncident, en faveur de l'expression non réflexive. A vrai dire, je n'avais jamais fait attention, et j'aurais accepté "s'arrêter de fumer" sans problème.